# Unsigned integer division ARM Cortex-M0+ Assembly

Tags: integer, assembly

I am writing a subroutine for unsigned integer division in Assembly. I will call the subroutine `DIVU`.

Inputs: `R1` will be the dividend. The divisor will be in `R0`.
Outputs: The quotient is going to be in `RO` and the remained in `R1`.

Basically, I am trying to make something like this:

```
R1 / R0 = R0remainderR1
```

If `R0=0`, I want to leave the input parameters unchanged and set the C flag when it returns. Otherwise, I just want to clear the C flag. I do not want to change any other registers' values after returning.

I have followed this idea:

> ```
> Quotient = 0; 
> while (Dividend >= Divisor) { 
>     Dividend -= Divisor; 
>     Quotient += 1;
> }
> Remainder = Dividend;
> ```

This is just a learning exercise, so the low performance of repeated subtraction is ok, [as discussed in comments on the original Stack Overflow question posted before writing this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481028/unsigned-integer-division-arm-cortex-m0-assembly#comment66301312_39481028).

And in Assembly this is what I produced:

```
DIVU
    CMP R1,#0       ;compares R1 to 0
    BEQ AnsZero     ;if R1=0, it branches to AnsZero (the final answer will be 0)
    CMP R0,#0       ;compares R0 to 0
    BEQ EndFlag     ;if R0=0, it will go to the end to set C flag
    PUSH    {R3, LR}        ;saves R3 so it can used as a counter for quotient
    MOV R3,#0       ;sets R3 to 0
    While   CMP R0,R1       ;start of while loop 
    BLT EndWhil     ;Branches to end of while when dividend < divisor, otherwise goes through loop
    SUB R1,R1,R0    ;R1=R1-R0 , dividend=dividend-divisor
    ADD R3,R3,#1    ;R3=R3+1, quotient=quotient+1 (init is zero, so 0+1=1 if one successful loop)
    B   While       ;continues loop

EndWhil MOV R0,R3       ;R0=R3, the register that had the divisor gets the quotient
    POP {R3, PC}        ;R3's original value is returned
    BX  LR      ;ends subroutine

EndFlag SUBS    R0,R0,#1 
    MOV     R0, #0  
    BX  LR      ;ends subroutine

AnsZero MOV R0,#0       ;sets R0=0 because R1=1, 0/X=0r0
    BX  LR      ;ends subroutine

    BX  LR      ;ends subroutine
```

Comment: @PeterCordes did you have the improved solution you had mentioned in the other thread?

Comment: Still working on it.  Thumb mode is difficult; there's no `MOV reg, #immediate`, only MOVS, so it's actually hard to return with the C flag set.  IDK if I can avoid saving/restoring a register in the return path that needs to have C set, just because ADD and SUB immediate are only available in their flag-setting forms.  It would be a lot more sensible to make callers check for divide by zero instead of doing this weird flag-return calling convention!

Comment: There is a MOV R#,R# instruction that won't set any flags if that is what you are trying to avoid. But thank you!

Comment: this is my handy list of things i know i can use http://imgur.com/a/PTh4Y (i took screenshots and posted on imgur for you)

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by having to save/restore a register, if I have to use an extra register to hold an immediate zero without setting flags.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980160/arm-assembly-cannot-use-immediate-values-and-adds-adcs-together and http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0432c/CHDCICDF.html.  BTW, the usual notation would be `MOV Rd, Rn` or something, not `R#`.  I first read that as `MOV Rd, #imm`

Comment: ohhh, okay. now i understand. yeah, that is a downside to this. but it is something i will need to know for school so i figured i might as well learn it lol edit: thanks for the notation tip btw

Comment: That table says `MOVS` only sets (N,Z) flags.  Does that mean it leaves C untouched, cleared, or undefined?  I was assuming cleared.  Hmm, http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cihcdbca.html says V is untouched, and implies C is also unaffected for immediate operands.

Comment: I think it means that the C flag is unchanged. the only changed flags would be the ones listed from what I have gathered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least a couple bugs.  [The LT condition is *signed* less-than](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/conditional.html).  You need BLO to branch on the unsigned Lower-Than condition (branch if Carry is unset).  See also [this article about carry vs. overflow](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt).

Also, I think you forgot to put the remainder into R1.

---

Your custom calling convention makes life difficult.  Flag return values appear to be cumbersome in Thumb mode, because many instructions are only available in flag-setting form.  (Cortex-M0 only supports Thumb mode, [with these instructions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0432c/CHDCICDF.html).)  It's also strange to not let your function clobber R2 and R3 like the standard calling convention allows.  This would reduce code-size for the function, although it would increase overall code size if there are many call sites.

It's normal to arrange a loop so the conditional branch is at the end. That reduces the instruction-count by one (removing the unconditional branch). Sometimes you need to test if the loop should even run once before falling into it, or jump to the test at the end, if you can't guarantee that it should always run at least once (`do{}while()` style).

You can combine the exit code-paths around AnsZero.  You have `MOV R0, #0` / `BX  LR` twice, so you should just put AnsZero pointing at the first one and leave out the second.  You also have two consecutive `BX  LR` instructions, where you previously had a `B` to the next line at the end of the function.  Never branch to the instruction that normal fall-through execution would take you to anyway.

---

[The comment character in ARM asm is `@`](https://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2010/02/11/hello-world-in-assembly).  `;` is used in x86 NASM / MASM, but the GNU assembler uses it to separate multiple instructions on the same line.  Maybe there are ARM assemblers that use `;` as a comment character, but making your code assemble with GAS seems like a good idea.  Note that `mov r3, #0` won't assemble with `-mcpu=cortex-m0`, [because `movs` is the only immediate-mov instruction it supports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30980781/224132).  Cortex-M0 has [very limited instruction choices](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0432c/CHDCICDF.html).

Further style points: use `:` after label names, even if your assembler syntax doesn't technically require it.  Some people may like to omit it when assembling data sections, but I don't think anyone likes it for code sections.

All-upper-case for asm instructions and register names is a valid choice.  I don't like it, but I guess it doesn't hurt.  Using it for symbol names is a bad idea, because you don't want to have to use all-caps names to call it from C.

Avoid useless comments like `CMP   R0,#0       ;compares R0 to 0`.  asm mnemonics are not *that* hard to decipher (except PowerPC).  Comment space is limited, don't waste it saying the same thing the reader learned from reading the code itself.

Leave blank spaces between logically-separate blocks of code, even when there aren't branches.  This improves human-readability.

I like to leave a space between operands in the operand list, like `cmp  r0, #0` instead of `cmp r0,#0`.

#### My version:

Always comment the top of your function with some high level description of input/output register usage.  Just like in a higher-level language, describe the contract the function makes with its caller.

My asm code usually ends up littered with comments about alternatives I decided against.  It's not an ideal example of good style.

```
.syntax unified     @ allow 2 or 3 operand forms of instructions.
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb              @ this is probably implied already by the .cpu

@@ input:  R0=divisor,  R1=dividend
@@ calculate R1/R0 by repeated subtraction
@@ output: R0=quotient, R1=remainder, C flag unset.
@@    or on division by zero: R0,R1 unchanged, C flag set.
@@ Other regs unmodified (even r2 and r3, which the normal calling convention allows functions to use as scratch regs)
.globl divu
divu:
      CMP   R1, #0         @ return 0,0 instead of divide error for the 0/0 corner case.
      BEQ   zero_dividend @ label names that describe why you go there are usually good.  Comments at the label can describe what happens there.

      CMP   R0, #0
      BEQ   div_by_zero

      @CMP   R0, R1        @ let this case fall through the loop once, instead of slowing down the common case to speed up this special case.
      @BLO   QuotientZero

      PUSH  {R3, LR}         @ LR doesn't make a good scratch reg, since many insns can only use low regs (R0-R7).  Push/popping it saves a BX LR
      MOVS  R3, #0           @ R3 = quotient = repeated-subtraction counter
@      LDR   R3, =#-1        @ account for the loop overshoot up-front.  But don't do this because cortex-m0 can't encode it in one insn other than a PC-relative load

sub_loop:                  @do{
      ADDS  R3, #1         @ quotient += 1.  (init is zero, so 0+1=1 if one successful loop)
      SUBS  R1, R0         @ dividend -= divisor and set flags,
      @ CMP   R0, R1       @ ...avoiding this cmp instruction.  Potentially a significant speedup for a tight loop.
      BLO   sub_loop       @} while(that didn't carry)@ i.e. while divisor was lower (unsigned) than the old value of dividend.

@EndWhile:
      @@ now we've subtracted one too many times.  Detecting that carry is the loop exit condition.
      @@ It's worth extra instructions outside the loop to save one inside the loop.
      @@ BUGFIX: original forgot to put the remainder in R1
      ADD   R1, R0         @ remainder, undoing the overshoot
      SUBS  R0, R3, #1     @  quotient, undoing the overshoot and clearing the C flag.
      @  Except that this will carry for 0xFFFFFFFF / 1.
      CMP   R0, R0         @ clear C flag.  TODO: avoid this otherwise-redundant instruction


      POP   {R3, PC}           @ return by popping straight into the PC

div_by_zero:      @@ We only get here with r0 == 0
      SUBS  R0, #1         @ Set the C flag and fall through to a mov the restores R0 to its original value

zero_dividend:    @@ CMP cleared the C flag
      MOVS  R0, #0         @ doesn't affect the C flag.   MOV Rd, #imm isn't available for Cortex-M0
      BX    LR
```

I'm not an ARM expert, and there may be a slight difference between popping into PC vs. running `BX LR`.  [`BX LR` can return from Thumb code to ARM code, or vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084857/what-does-bx-lr-do-in-arm-assembly-language), but popping into PC can't.  AFAIK, either is fine for Thumb -> Thumb returns which are your only option [on a Cortex-M0](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0432c/CHDCICDF.html).

This really does assemble.  I didn't test it, but the disassembly looks like we'd expect (which is a useful sanity check):

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -d arm-divu.o 

arm-divu.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <divu>:
   0:   2900            cmp     r1, #0
   2:   d00a            beq.n   1a <zero_dividend>
   4:   2800            cmp     r0, #0
   6:   d007            beq.n   18 <div_by_zero>
   8:   b508            push    {r3, lr}
   a:   2300            movs    r3, #0

0000000c <sub_loop>:
   c:   3301            adds    r3, #1
   e:   1a09            subs    r1, r1, r0
  10:   d3fc            bcc.n   c <sub_loop>
  12:   4401            add     r1, r0
  14:   1e58            subs    r0, r3, #1
  16:   4280            cmp     r0, r0
  18:   bd08            pop     {r3, pc}

0000001a <div_by_zero>:
  1a:   3801            subs    r0, #1

0000001c <zero_dividend>:
  1c:   2000            movs    r0, #0
  1e:   4770            bx      lr
```

I don't know much at all about tuning for Cortex-M0, but perhaps aligning the top of `sub_loop` would be good.  Maybe to a 16-byte boundary, or at least so all three instructions are in the same 16-byte block.  (Currently the branch is in the next block after the ADDS/SUBS.)

Comment: This is great! I do enjoy your commenting, it makes it really easy to follow what is happening with the code. Is the sub-loop just a loop in a subroutine, or is there more to it?

Comment: @JasonR: It's a loop that subtracts...   It's an attempt to be more descriptive with the labels than `While` :)   And thanks, yeah my code may be cluttered, but I think I'm pretty good at writing comments that explains what's going on at the higher level, not just describing what the asm instructions already say.

Comment: okay. i thought it was something simple, was just double checking your naming thought. im gonna read through the rest of the code and comments you made and try to learn it all. thanks for spending the time on this